# Access cookies for external sites

Tags: angular, architecture, session-cookies

I have the following scenario.

[image]

MY-API and MY-ANG are installed in the same server, they have communication between them. In other server I have installed another web site (EXT-APP). Before to access EXT-APP the user have to login, and after login he can access EXT-APP that uses a cookie to store some data needed to navigate to some resources in the site.

My goal is to be able from MY-API or MY-ANG to get this cookie. But I don't know how to go through the login page and then get the cookie from my sites.

Is there any technique to reproduce the login flow and get the cookie in my sites?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I believe your "ext-site" should set the cookie  and include the `domain` attribute of you ng-app. This answer here provides good details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139/821918